# I switched to using "import * as " and encountered error: Entity is not defined

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, serverless-stack

I used "import * as Article" instead of "import { Article }," and then an error occurred when I ran "yarn dev". The error is:

```
jiahao@jiahaodeMacBook-Air-2 graphql-sst-sample % yarn dev
yarn run v1.22.19
$ npm run env:local sst dev

> graphql-sst-sample@0.0.0 env:local
> env-cmd -f .env.local -- sst dev

SST v2.16.3  ready!

➜  App:     graphql-sst-sample
   Stage:   develop
   Console: https://console.sst.dev/graphql-sst-sample/develop

✖  Pothos: Failed to extract schema:
   Entity is not defined

✔  Deployed:
   Database
   Api
   API: https://hogt05y159.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
   Web
```

Here is the code change of my repo:

```
-import { Article } from "../../../../core/src/article";
+import * as Article from "../../../../core/src/article";
```

The PR of my repo:
https://github.com/kody-liou/graphql-sst-sample/pull/4

The steps to reproduce error:

## Prerequest

1. Install nvm:

Follow the instructions at https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm to install nvm.

2. Install Node.js 18:
   Run the following command to install Node.js 18 using nvm:

```bash
nvm install 18
```

3. Install Yarn:
   Run the following command to install Yarn globally:

```bash
npm i -g yarn
```

4. Create an AWS account
5. Create a .env.local file in the project's root folder with the following content:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your access key id
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your secret access key
# Region ap-northeast-1 is at tokyo
AWS_REGION=ap-northeast-1
NODE_ENV=development
```

## Getting Started

1. Open the JavaScript Debug Terminal and execute the following command:

```bash
yarn dev
```

2. Open another terminal and execute the following command:

```bash
yarn dev:web
```

I expect after I run "yarn dev", the error message:

```
✖  Pothos: Failed to extract schema:
   Entity is not defined
```

will disappear.

Comment: Why does the this module reexport itself? https://github.com/kody-liou/graphql-sst-sample/blob/e9e6146eb04f75ae194a470d34c9785f16911918/packages/core/src/article.ts#L5

Comment: It is re-exporting itself since I created my project using this command: 
npx create-sst@latest --template=graphql/dynamo

Comment: Well, it doesn't make a lot of sense.